# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException is thrown when DeserializeObject<> is called

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Excuse my ignorance since I'm a newbie. I'm trying to get stream info from Twitch whether the stream is live or not. I'm doing this by using `HttpClient` and GET request. The class `TwitchData` deserialize JSON as object is the following.

```
public partial class TwitchData
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Datum[] Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pagination")]
    public Pagination Pagination { get; set; }
}

public partial class Datum
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("game_id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long GameId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("community_ids")]
    public object[] CommunityIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("viewer_count")]
    public long ViewerCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("started_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset StartedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("thumbnail_url")]
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
}

public partial class Pagination
{
    [JsonProperty("cursor")]
    public string Cursor { get; set; }
}

public partial class TwitchData
{
    public static TwitchData FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitchData>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this TwitchData self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        long l;
        if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
        {
            return l;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (long)untypedValue;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
        return;
    }

    public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
}
```

I do the HttpClient GET request with the following

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string uri = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=59980349";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Client-ID", token);
var result = client.GetStringAsync(uri);
jsonString = result.ToString();
twitchData = PwdResetRequest.FromJson(jsonString);
```

When this is run, `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException, Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0` is thrown. Further debugging, I found that the program breaks at line 71 which is

```
public static TwitchData FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitchData>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
```

since I got this class from [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com), I don't know how to fix that line or why the Exception is thrown.

**EDIT:** 
 JSON is requested in comments. This is the JSON if the stream is live

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "30356128676",
      "user_id": "59788312",
      "game_id": "498652",
      "community_ids": [],
      "type": "live",
      "title": "A stream",
      "viewer_count": 1325,
      "started_at": "2018-09-07T16:30:09Z",
      "language": "en",
      "thumbnail_url": "url"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "cursor": "eydBIjpwdWGsLaJhIjp7IkGH4hNl6CH6MXr9"
  }
}
```

and when its offline

```
{
  "data": [],
  "pagination": {}
}
```

Comment: Paste the json.

Comment: I have added the json, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question an hour ago?

Comment: First post had 2 questions instead of focusing on one thing. I have split them so that it's easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you sure you only receive those two json string? because it work good

Comment: I tested using `curl -H 'Client-ID: token' \ -X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=streamID` and can get the JSON. The program gets the JSON as well. Exception is thrown when the given line is executed.

Comment: Clearly the problem is with the content of the `json` variable you pass to the deserialization routine. Inspect the content of the variable. Do not blindly assume the variable has the "correct" content (=correct JSON string) just because you can get the expected JSON string by some other means. When inspecting this variable -- i guess it's a string -- pay utmost attention to any possible unwanted non-printable character (like \0x00 or other "invisible" characters) at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I don't see any error with the mentioned Json payloads. Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9QUXm) dotnet fiddle.

Comment: The error message you got means that the Json parser encountered a character in the provided string that does not comply with the (relaxed) JSON syntax. As the error message gave no or an non-printable character (`''`) as the problematic character at line 0, position 0, chances are the `json` variable might be empty or contain a problematic non-printable character at the very beginning...

Comment: to start with, you are calling client.GetStringAsync(uri); without using await, so that jsonString most likely does NOT actually contain the JSON you think it does